# Android - alarm clock with Notification using AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm, notificationmanager

I'm creating an alarm clock using AlarmManager and I have some troubles:

1. How to stop sounding of notification when I open Notification?
2. How to make alarm for a certain day of week (or the whole week), not for the certain date?

   ```
   private void restartNotify()
   {
       Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   // current Month - 1
   calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
   calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 28);

   calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
   calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
   calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
   calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

   Intent timeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimeNotification.class);
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, timeIntent, 0);

   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
   ```

   }

   ```
   public class TimeNotification extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver
   {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)
       {
           Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
           if (alarmUri == null) {
               alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
           }
           Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
           ringtone.play();

           //this will send a notification message
           ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                   AlarmService.class.getName());
           startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
           setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
       }
   }
   ```

   public class AlarmService extends IntentService
         {

   ```
       private NotificationManager alarmNotificationManager;

   public AlarmService() {
       super("AlarmService");
   }

   @Override
   public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
   {
       sendNotification("Wake Up! Wake Up!");
   }

   private void sendNotification(String msg)
   {
       alarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
               .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

       PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
               new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

       NotificationCompat.Builder alamNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
               this).setContentTitle("Alarm").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_btn_radio_material)
               .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
               .setContentText(msg);


       alamNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
       alarmNotificationManager.notify(1, alamNotificationBuilder.build());
   }
   ```